# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, How to solve this error ? Im using vue js and laravel 7

Tags: laravel

This is my my vue component

```
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            form:new Form({
                district: '',
                province: '',
                name: '',
            })
        }
    },
    methods: {
        createHousehold(){
            this.form.post('api/household');

        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
```

This is the api route.

```
Route::apiResource('household','APIController/HouseholdController');
```

When I check the route list 'api/household' has get for index and post for storing, but I get this error and not able to figure out where do I specify the post method other than in the vue method. Also I tried adding csrf in the head section of my master blade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**
You will need to set the Access-Control-Allow-Methods header the specifies the method or methods allowed when accessing the resource in response to a preflight request.

Ref URL - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods

you can add cors package in server-side by using the following package(in laravel or PHP)

URL - https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors

> composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors

Add in the middleware group under the **app/Http/Kernel.php** file.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    ...
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ],
    ...
]
```

and run the following command.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cors"
```

update the config with the following content(**config/cors.php**)

```
return [
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'], // this is the solution of your problem
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
]
```

Comment: Try with header function of the PHP for setting value

Comment: And sometime you will need to restart the project and the server to change the effect.

Comment: Than you, I solved it using fruitcake/laravel-cors, and updating the allow methods

Comment: I hope you follow the ref. link as this link also specifies the "fruitcake/laravel-cors
" package. https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors#user-content-installation